# Run Widget-extension without launching main App

Tags: ios, swift, widget, today-extension

I'm implementing a widget in my iOS App. (accessed through 3D-Touching on the App Icon).
However, when tapping anywhere on the widget it automatically opens the App. (The widget still runs all it's functions, but it opens the App when it's done). The widget does not open the app when used as a Today View Extension.
What I want is the widget to run all it's functions without opening the actual main App.

I know that this worked until a while ago, and I feel like the behaviour changed after upgrading to the newest macOS, iOS and Xcode versions. Is there any way to revert the Widget to it's original behaviour?

––––

Upon further investigation I created a new project and added a today extension to it to find out, that tapping anywhere on the widget opened the app (but only when running as a widget, not in today view). Therefore I guess this to be the expected (new) behavior.

However, as long as this is not an Xcode bug I would expect there to be a way of continuing to use the old behavior. If anybody experiences the same issue or found any solutions I would be thankful for any help.